# Qt doesn't recognize Standard libs

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, std

I'm struggling finding why my Qt does not recognize anymore any of the std libs like: iostream or List.
I'll better explain with some snaps:

[image]

The funny thing is that was correctly recognizing them yesterday, then, for some reason seems that I did something wrong and now I got that error, plus, if I try to run it, it will perfectly work.

My .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = PhotoShock
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        blur.cpp \
        flip.cpp \
        hsl_process.cpp \
        imghandling.cpp \
        kernels.cpp \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
        matrix_filters.cpp \
        process.cpp \
        rgb_process.cpp \
        rotation.cpp

HEADERS += \
    blur.h \
    flip.h \
    hsl_process.h \
        imghandling.h \
    kernels.h \
        mainwindow.h \
    matrix_filters.h \
    process.h \
    rgb_process.h \
    rotation.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.3.4.6.dylib
LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.3.4.6.dylib


QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config
CONFIG  += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv


# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    test/lib/library.json
```

And I'm using Qt creator 4.9.1 Based on Qt 5.12.3, on OSX Mojave.

Comment: Check your Kit configuration. Maybe, your compiler is not well configured

Comment: Hi Romha! thanks for that, I checked it and I set the Gcc instead of the default one stetted, don't know why it changed, but finally is working! I'll set your comment as answer if you post it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Romha Korev said well, changing the compiler configuration was the key for let everything work again.